# Qt window frame design

Tags: c++, qt

How to apply the design of window frame?

Not `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` , but Windows 7 frame

edit: 
How to create your own frame in QStyle?

Comment: could you please tell me the exact need ?

Comment: Are you talking about styles? Motif, Windows, GTK+?

Comment: I need to create own style ( instead of default Windows style)

Comment: I know this is quite old, but recently I've developed a base program with custom borders (even resizeable). So, if somebody else needs here is the link: github.com/Nintersoft/CustomTitlebar

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about frame style, it will be good solution.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWindowsStyle>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle(new QWindowsStyle);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But Qt has many other styles - learn about QMotifStyle and QCleenlooksStyle... [[link]](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwindowsstyle.html)

Comment: Hm.It seems to have the opportunity to create their own style, but I do not understand how to make their own frames

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try Coffe or Pagefold styles.
2. You can set a style sheet on an individual child widget, on a whole window, or even on a whole application by calling QWidget::setStyleSheet() or QApplication::setStyleSheet().

Answer (score 0):

Frames are usually the business of the windowing system and cannot be freely re-styled by the application. You'd probably need to create a frameless window with mentioned hint and paint your own title bar/frame inside the widget.